# How to join tables based on XPath results in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, select

I've got a table `views` with a column containing XML documents (stored as `text`). Here's a simplified version:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view>
  <image>
    <sequence>
      <param name="scan">129</param>
    </sequence>
  </image>
  <image>
    <sequence>
      <param name="scan">1</param>
    </sequence>
  </image>
  [...]
</view>
```

Another table contains the scans referenced in the XML. If refactoring into a new table is impractical at the moment, how do I connect the two tables in an SQL query?

Answer (score 3):

If your PostgreSQL has been compiled with `--with-libxml`, the following query should work:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM views
  JOIN scans ON scans.id = ANY (
           xpath(
               '/view/image/sequence/param[@name = "scan"]/text()',
                views.xml::xml)::text[]::int[])
;
```

That is:

1. Cast `views.xml` from `text` to `xml`.
2. Get all the scan ID values as an array of `xml` using `xpath()`.
3. [Cast the `xml` array to an array of `text` and then an array of `int`](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/proposal-casting-from-XML-to-int-numeric-text-tp1979792p1979797.html) (you can't cast `xml[]` to `int[]` directly, at least in PostgreSQL 9.2).
4. Check that at least one of the scan IDs from the XML matches.